# createElement button seems to submit form instead of function call

Tags: javascript, createelement

So, I've created a button element with javascript. All seems to have went quite well for that.

```
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary');
    btn.setAttribute('style', 'float: right; display: inline-block; margin-top: 3px; margin-right: 15px;');
    btn.innerHTML = 'Remove Attachment';
    btn.setAttribute('onclick', 'removeAttachment(' + i + ')');
```

Problem I'm encountering is that when I click the button, it doesn't call the removeAttachment function, but rather seems like it's submitting the page form. Am I missing something with making the button only be bound to the onclick event and not tied to the form?

All I'm really wanting to do is operate on some DOM elements rather than issue a post or get.
Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A button's default type is `submit`.

Comment: If you place the button inside the page form it automatically becomes ”tied” to the form and works as its submit button by default. The easiest way to fix it is to give the button the attribute `type` with a value of `”button”`

Comment: Yeah, but when you force an onclick event handler, doesn't that override the default action?

Comment: @Lennholm A button doesn't become a submit button by default.

Comment: @Lennholm - THAT was the ticket!!! Adding 'type' attribute fixed the issue. Thank you so much!!! :)

Comment: No, but you can prevent the default action by invoking the `preventDefault()` method on the event object. That’s another way of solving your problem.

Comment: It only does that if the event handler returns false.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Yes it does if it’s placed within a form

Comment: @Lennholm the specs say otherwise: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-button-type

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Maybe you should look at that spec one more time. *”The missing value default and invalid value default are the Submit Button state”*. Or even better, just test it for yourself.

Comment: Ahh yes okay... I didn't see that... I saw a few lines below where it says `Button: do nothing` I read that as the tag type not attribute.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you are creating the button using javascript there really isn't a need to add the javascript to the html. So, use `addEventListener` instead to add a click event to the javascript instead of the HTML.

To prevent the form from submitting, use `preventDefault()`

```
btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  removeAttachment(i)
});
```

Another option is to set the type of button instead of `preventDefault()`:

```
btn.type = 'button'
```

Here is a working example with `preventDefault()`

```js
var i = 0;

var btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary');
btn.setAttribute('style', 'float: right; display: inline-block; margin-top: 3px; margin-right: 15px;');
btn.innerHTML = 'Remove Attachment';
btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  removeAttachment(i)
});

document.querySelector('form').appendChild(btn)

function removeAttachment(i) {
  console.log('Remove Attachment:', i)
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">

</form>
```

Here is a working example using `type="button"`

```js
var i = 0;

var btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary');
btn.setAttribute('style', 'float: right; display: inline-block; margin-top: 3px; margin-right: 15px;');
btn.innerHTML = 'Remove Attachment';
btn.type = 'button'
btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => removeAttachment(i));

document.querySelector('form').appendChild(btn)

function removeAttachment(i) {
  console.log('Remove Attachment:', i)
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">

</form>
```

Comment: Awesome suggestion. Unfortunately, it's still acting the same way. I thought, for sure, that this would remedy the issue.